# Sparkline entire column of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

I have a column of data, the number of rows may change often. I want to create a sparkline of the entire row of data without specifying the cell for last row because it'll change. How would I do it? The first number does NOT begin at A1, so I can't use A:A. For example if the column has 30 rows of data, then I want sparkline(A10:A40), but if it changes to 35 rows, then I want sparkline(A10:A45). Is there a function that automates this so I don't have to retype sparkline() every time?

Comment: it also depends on the version, please specify which version do you use,

Comment: Google Spreadsheet and Excel 2013.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I removed the Google Spreadsheet tag so your question is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Excel 2013 or higher, why don't you use a named range for the Data Range?  You can specify the Named Range from cells $A$1:$A$100 and call it "Values".  When you create your sparkline, you just type Values as the Data Range.  If you only have A1:A30 filled with data, then only they will show.  If you have data outside of that and includes up to A100, then the sparkline will adjust accordingly.